# add element and then drag it

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

actually i dont know why it doesnt work.

I have a column that contains three div. When you click on one, it's added as a new object in another div (i get the id and proceed to give it to the new object with a '0' behind).

Now, when that div is added, i want it to be draggable, thus used i the simple jquery function.

```
function addObject(idOfObject) {

    var elediv = document.createElement('div');

    if(idOfObject == 1)
    {
        elediv.style.background ="lightblue";
        elediv.innerHTML = '1';     
    }

    else if(idOfObject == 2)
    {
        elediv.style.background ="yellow";
        elediv.innerHTML = '2';     
    }

    else if(idOfObject == 3)
    {
        elediv.style.background ="lightgreen";
        elediv.innerHTML = '3';
    }

    elediv.setAttribute('id', idOfObject + '0');
    elediv.setAttribute('class', 'elementAdded');

    document.getElementById("workzone").appendChild(elediv);
}

$(function() {

    $( "div.elementAdded" ).draggable();

});
```

What's wrong with that code?

Here is the html part:

```
<div id="elecolumn">
    <header>Add an element</header>

    <div class="elementAjoutable" id="1" onclick="addObject(this.id)" style="background:lightblue;">1</div>
    <div class="elementAjoutable" id="2" onclick="addObject(this.id)" style="background:yellow;">2</div>
    <div class="elementAjoutable" id="3" onclick="addObject(this.id)" style="background:lightgreen;">3</div></div>  

</div>

<div id="workzone"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this

```
$(elediv).draggable();
```

After this

```
document.getElementById("workzone").appendChild(elediv);
```

Here's a [working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/uUMDk/3/)

The way you're doing it now, it's trying to make your `elementAdded` div draggable before it's even been added to the page.

Also, a good way to shorten your code:

```
function addObject(idOfObject, color) {

    var elediv = document.createElement('div');

    elediv.style.background = color;
    elediv.innerHTML = idOfObject;

    elediv.setAttribute('id', idOfObject + '0');
    elediv.setAttribute('class', 'elementAdded');

    document.getElementById("workzone").appendChild(elediv);
    $(elediv).draggable();
}
```

Then call it in your HTML this way:

```
...onclick="addObject(this.id, this.style.background)"...
```